# .so file used in Eclipse

Tags: android, file, android-studio, shared-libraries

How do use same `.so` file in android Studio which I have been using in eclipse? Like Rgb change and filters effects so files. It would be a great help if u could provide me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Adding .so Library in Android Studio**

1. Create Folder "jniLibs" inside "src/main/"
2. Put all your .so libraries inside "src/main/jniLibs" folder
3. Folder structure looks like,

   |--app:

   |--|--src:

   |--|--|--main

   |--|--|--|--jniLibs

   |--|--|--|--|--armeabi

   |--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files
4. No extra code requires just sync your project and run your application.

Comment: After adding so file  "cannot Resolve Corresponding JniFunction."                                                                          static {
  System.loadLibrary("NdkDemo2");
 }
 public static native Bitmap applyBlurEffect(Bitmap bitmap, Bitmap bitmap2);                                                                                              "applyBlurEffect" shows Red Color Mark.

Comment: I appreciate the time you have put into detailing these requirements. Thank you Harshad